# How to look at individual values from a variable in a statistical test

Tags: r, statistics, statistical-test

I have this solution which allows me to look at values of my type column individually in a fisher test. (can also swap out fisher for chisq.test)

But i tried to apply this to an anova test and had errors.

This is my original version

```
# fisher test status on types individually 
fish = lapply(unique(df$type),function(i){
  ctest = fisher.test(table(df$type == i, df$status))
  data.frame(type = i, pvalue = ctest$p.value)
})
```

And i get this output which is my same desired output for an anova test

```
type        pvalue

warning     7.94658438e-23
noncontact  5.84265922e-01
issue       4.18245681e-04
success     1.67653259e-09
```

This is an attempt I tried for anova test  but got this error

```
anov = lapply(unique(df$numtype),function(i){
  atest = aov(table(df$numtype == i ~ df$status))
  data.frame(numtype = i, pvalue = atest$p.value)
})


Error: unique() applies to only vectors
```

And I am using a dataframe, which i didn't think would be a problem.

My columns used are like this (numeric columns only intended for anova ofcourse)

| afluence | type | numtype | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | noncontact | 1 | positive |
| 2 | warning | 2 | declined |
| 3 | issue | 3 | positive |
| 4 | success | 4 | positive |
| 5 | success | 1 | NA |
| 6 | success | 5 | positive |

Does anyone know how to make this work for an anova test?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need this?

```
lapply(split(df, df$numtype),function(x){
  atest = aov(numtype~status, x)
  data.frame(numtype = x$numtype[1], pvalue = atest$p.value)
}) -> result

result
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I get an error :/ "'Error in data.frame(numtype = x$numtype[1], pvalue = atest$p.value': Arguments imply differing number of rows: 1,0"

Comment: @i_love_whiteboards Can you provide data in a reproducible format so that I can test my code against the data. Edit your post by including output of `dput(df)`.